# Can I have two databases related session-factory tags in a single hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

I have two different databases where I need to connect and update the tables dynamically.
But it looks like I cannot keep two sessions related information in configuration file.
Is there any way to handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as you noticed, the root element of Hibernate's XML configuration file must declare one and only one `<session-factory>` element as per the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT hibernate-configuration (session-factory,security?)>
```

So if you want to configure multiple session factories, either:

- Use a [programmatic configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic) approach
- Use several `hibernate.cfg.xml`

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [3.1. Programmatic configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic)
  - [3.7. XML configuration file](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig)